# Left Join issue in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.camp_id AS camp_id,
                c.camp_key AS camp_key,
                c.camp_active AS camp_active,
                c.camp_deleted AS camp_deleted,
                c.camp_name AS camp_name,
                c.camp_cpc AS camp_cpc,
                c.camp_destination AS camp_destination,
                camp_token1,
                camp_token2,
                camp_token3,
                camp_token4,
                camp_token5,
                camp_token6,
                camp_token7,
                camp_token8,
                camp_token9,
                camp_token10,
                token1_field,
                token2_field,
                token3_field,
                token4_field,
                token5_field,
                token6_field,
                token7_field,
                token8_field,
                token9_field,
                token10_field,
                group_name,
                group_id,
                source_id,
                source_name,
                user_name
                FROM mt_campaigns c
                LEFT JOIN mt_offers USING (camp_id)
                LEFT JOIN mt_groups USING (group_id)
                LEFT JOIN mt_traffic_sources USING (source_id)
                LEFT JOIN mt_account WHERE c.owner_id = mt_account.user_id
                WHERE camp_deleted=0
```

Now I want to join another table(mt_account) which has a column called user_id and it matches with the the owner_id column of the mt_canpaigns.

How can i edit the join query?

Comment: Just add the join part `left join mt_account mta on mta.user_id = c.owner_id` before the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
LEFT JOIN mt_account WHERE c.owner_id=mt_account.user_id
```

for

```
LEFT JOIN mt_account ON c.owner_id=mt_account.user_id
```

You need to use `ON` to define the fields you want to join on instead of `WHERE`